# Handling backpressure and avoiding rebalances on a slow consumer kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

The use case is that my consumer does some I/O job that takes a long time, occasionally. I am using Spring 2.0.1 and `<spring-cloud.version>Elmhurst.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version</spring-cloud.version>`

The initial solution was to set `max.poll.interval.ms` to a higher value and `max.poll.records` to a lower value than default. This did reduce the number of rebalances but there are still cases when the I/O operations take longer than `max.poll.interval.ms` and rebalances are quite costly, generating quite some lag. Should there be no rebalances the processing would finish in a timely manner, even considering the situations when the I/O duration spikes.

What settings and code or architecture could I use to make the system both responsive (rebalance when a consumer is actually blocked) without triggering rebalances when one consumer takes an unusually long time to process a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I am aware of is to tweak those two properties (or reduce the time taken by the listener).

Comment: Is there really no way for a specific consumer to notice that he's taking too long to process things and tell kafka "hey, I'm here and alive, not stuck, guaranteed don't panic if I don't poll() for n more milliseconds"? I've made some attempts with consumer.pause() and consumer.resume() but no dice, especially when message processing takes longer than session.timeout.ms

Comment: No; there is no such mechanism, `pause()` doesn't help - that just tells Kafka to not return any records from a `poll()` but it still requires a poll within `max.poll.interval.ms`. You could hand off the work to another thread, set `max.poll.records=1`, and `pause()` the consumer; use manual acks; then ack/resume when the job is complete. Bottom line is Kafka is not really the best choice for this use case,

Answer (score 0):

If you need backpressure mechanism for Kafka, I am afraid you need help form additional frameworks like Akka'a [Alpakka Kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#back-pressure-explained) with their [contributions](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/alpakka-kafka-flow-control-optimizations) to Kafka code base.

If you need sample code, you can look my blogs, [blog1](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/alpakka-kafka-stream-and-akka-finite-state-machine/), [blog2](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/).